# Is it ok to skip a TargetSdkVersion (27 to 29) for a library project?

Tags: android

I've inherited a codebase for a library project written in native android that hasn't been updated in a while, where the targetSdkVersion for the project is 27. In testing apps integrating the library that are on api 28, we haven't run into any specific issues. I want to update the targetSdkVersion 29 given that Android Q is about ready to be released out of beta, but I'm wondering if I can increment the targetSdkVersion from 27 directly to 29 without having missed any potential version bugs in 28, or if I have to increment to 28, test and then increment to 29?

Comment: it doesn't matter if you do 28 and then 29 or 29 directly, as long as you make sure to go over google's notes about changes in both releases and make sure you make the required updates

Comment: Thanks. Are there any tools outside of using Android studio that I can use to check for compatibility? I guess using Xlinter with the appropriate flags would account for that right? (Apart from having to go through and test)

Comment: compatibility of what?

Comment: Of the various components (Ui and others) of my library against the latest api. I'm wondering if I can do a scan of my project without having to test to catch issues.

Comment: That would be nice, I am afraid this is a manual task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 types of errors that can occur while upgrading:

> **1. Google removed a method or class, that you have used.**

In this case you won't be able to compile your project without an lint/gradle error message. So, you will notice these kind of changes.

> **2. Google changed some class behaviours or introduced new access patterns**

These are harder to spot, since you will probably only find out about it, when you use it. An example is the cleartext support in Android 9 ([Cleartext](https://medium.com/@son.rommer/fix-cleartext-traffic-error-in-android-9-pie-2f4e9e2235e6)). Your app will crash, if you target Android 9 and forget to add the necessary line in your manifest, but it will run perfectly on pre Android 9.

In the end, there are no tools for detecting this (at least I dont know them). The best would be to create a working testing procedure (multiple testing devices and user) and to scan the changenotes on the developer page for announcements.

Comment: *or to scan the changenotes* - what do you mean "or". Checking those notes is an absolute must

Comment: Depends. If you got a good testing procedure, the error will be discovered almost immediately.

Comment: and then you have to read the notes to figure out how to fix them anyway. Might as well start there and save QA people some time

Comment: Our QA process kind of sparse. Decided that for now I'm opting to set targetSdk to 28, integrate it into the project i'm working on currently and catch any errors as I build stuff. Then when 29 comes out of beta, I won't have an excuse and will have to update both the app and the library to 29